# Stacked ng bootstrap modal lose focus

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap, angular-calendar

I have a ng bootstrap modal with an angular-calendar inside of it (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar#getting-started) like this:

[image]

When I click in a day with a badge I open another modal, but when I close this second modal I can't make scroll in the calendar modal.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same bug when trying to stack a ng-bootstrap modal above an other one.

My fix was to create and use a [ng-bootstrap-modal-stack](https://github.com/bastienmoulia/ng-bootstrap-modal-stack) library with a secondary modal.

Comment: Finally I save the first modal reference in the second modal. When I open the second modal I use the reference to close the first one. When the second is closed I use the saved reference to open the first and the focus is retrieved. Also, I  have to save the data associated with the modal to retrieve the same state.